# Permutation and combination problem - word arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

This is a question of permutation and combination. 
Q. How many words can be formed from the word "LUCKNOW" when

i) No restriction is there

ii) L is the first letter of the word

iii) All the vowels are together

iv) L always occurs before U

v) L always occurs before U and U always occurs before W

I have managed to solve i), ii) and iii), but no. iv) and v) I can't solve. Please help me with explanation to solve it.

Comment: For iv): you choose 2 places of the 7 places you have, and permute the other letters in the other 5 places. The other case is analog.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @blue66, (iv) May be looked at as finding anagrams of "XXXCKNO", where the "X" are <I>placeholders</I> to be filled with the L,U,W in order.  That is a permutation of seven symbols of which three are repeated: $\frac{7!}{3!}$

Comment: Do the words formed have to be seven letters long?

Answer (score 2):

i) All are distinct letters so, and there are 7 letters, all permutations will work which is equal to $7!$.

ii) L is first letter means, the rest letters are only allowed to be permuted, so 6 remaining letters so answer is all permutations of 6 letters i.e. $6!$.

iii) All vowels are together, you have for vowels here U and O, so in a word they always come together (As a block) and in 2 ways either UO or OU, all the words with UO is permutation of 5 letters and this one block, i.e. $(5+1)!$ and similarly for the other block, hence you have $2\times 6!$ in total.

iv) Note given a word, L either comes before U or after U. But suppose you have a word with U first and L coming afterwards, then if you switch the positions you have a corresponding word with L first and U coming afterwards, so they come in pairs, so they partition all words into two equal sets, so answer for this is $(7!)/2$.

v) Using the same logic as before, in a word where ..L..U..W.., is needed, if the word contains in any other order then just interchange places to get teh required order. So here we have more possibilities i.e. $3! = 6$ ways, they come in a set of 6, hence the partion is into 6 equal size sets hence the answer will be $(7!)/6$.

*In the above problem, I have assumed that I have to use all the letters to form the word, but if that is not the case, the values may vary but the logic still works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood no. iv) but I still have problem understanding the last one. Can you please explain with examples (may be with some small numbers). Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

Updated

For v) There are 5 positions for L (first 5 positions)
 The possible permutations of LUW for the first position of L equate to the 5th triangular number since there are 5+4+3+2+1 = 15 permutations of UW

For the second position of L we get the 4th triangular number = 10 and so on

Giving a total of  15 + 10 + 6 + 3 + 1 = 35 permutations for LUW for each of which there are 4! ways of arranging the other 4 letters.

So I make that 35*4! Which agrees with the answer from DiffeoR but may offer another way of looking at it.